# Android Cuttlefish Device Not Booting - launch_cvd Command Not Working (Error: run_cvd returned 23)

Tags: android, ubuntu, command-line, android-emulator, emulation

I have built a custom ROM that I'm testing on Android Cuttlefish, but when I go to boot the device on the command line using the launch_cvd command, I get the following errors:

1. [assemble_cvd ... fetcher_config.cpp:212] Could not find file ending in kernel
2. [assemble_cvd ... fetcher_config.cpp 212] Could not find file ending in initramfs.img
3. run_cvd returned 23
4. Subprocess 39641 exited with error code: 23

The main issue seems to lie in the 'error 23' that is returned by run_cvd.

I have tried Google searching and browsing popular forums where Android is built and debugged (XDA Forums, Reddit, StackOverflow, the Android Building Google Group, YouTube, and the web in general). I have also posted on Reddit and will post on the Android Building Google Group. Additionally, I have looked through the source code for Cuttlefish on Google's Git repo to find why the program is outputting the error to no avail.

Lastly, I read through the logfiles of Cuttlefish to see the errors outputted by Cuttlefish. The kernel.log file seems to show the kernel booted successfully (despite the command line saying that it couldn't find the kernel file), I would imagine the same is true of initramfs.img, but I have no way of confirming that initramfs.img was successfully found by launch_cvd. The logcat file is empty (likely because the Cuttlefish failed to boot) and launcher.log simply reproduces the output on the command line (which contain the four errors I listed above).

Could anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do ps -A | grep crosvm to see if crosvm is running already.
If it is do stop_cvd || true or kill crosvm process with process PID.

Comment: Hi Vuko, thank you so much for responding to my question. I have been stuck on this issue for days. crosvm isn't already running before I start 'launch_cvd', is running after I start 'launch_cvd', and is terminated when I run 'stop_cvd' so it seems to be working properly. Do you have any other solutions to the problem? To give a little context, the errno 23 I was receiving earlier was because I had ran 'launch_cvd' two times in a row, causing the # of processes to hit the max allowed on Ubuntu, but launch_cvd is still giving me the 'kernel and initramfs.img not found' errors :(